# Type mismatch array(VBA) in recursion function

Tags: arrays, vba, recursion

I' m exploring VBA in Excel a little bit and try to run recursive fast fourier transform code but I get message

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

in function `recFFT(ByRef X() As Double) As Double()` (see line `Fe = recFFT(Xe())`).

This is the code:

```vb
Function recFFT(ByRef X() As Double) As Double()
Dim n, m, i, k As Integer
Dim Xe(), Xo(), Fe(), Fo() As Double
Dim wcos As Double

    n = UBound(X)

If n = 1 Then
    recFFT = X
Else
    m = n / 2
    
    ReDim Xe(0 To m - 1)
    ReDim Xo(0 To m - 1)
 
    For i = 0 To m - 1
        Xe(i) = X(2 * i)
        Xo(i) = X(2 * i + 1)    
    Next i

    ReDim Fe(0 To m - 1)
    Fe = recFFT(Xe())
    
    ReDim Fo(0 To m - 1)
    Fo = recFFT(Xo())
    
    ReDim freqbins(0 To n - 1)
    
    For k = 0 To n / 2 - 1 
        wcos = Cos(2 * PI * k / n) * Fo(k)
        freqbins(k) = Fe(k) + wcos
        freqbins(k+n/2) = Fe(k) - wcos      
    Next k
    
    recFFT = freqbins()
    
End If
    
End Function
```

Function is called from sub routine by `F = ThisWorkbook.recFFT(A())` where `F` and `A` are arrays declared as Double.

Tried to find solution online but nothing helped so far.

I am not sure if this type of recursive call is even possible in VBA script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dim Xe() As Double, Xo() As Double, Fe() As Double, Fo() As Double` - you have to actually repeat the variable type, otherwise it's implicitly `Variant`.

Comment: `PI` - probably should be `WorksheetFunction.Pi`.

Comment: You need `Dim freqBins() As Double` too, or `recFFT = freqbins()` will fail.